# How to make NUnit stop executing tests in a Class on a failure

Tags: nunit

Is there any way to make NUnit abort running any more tests *in that class only* when it encounters the first error? I'm running integration tests, using the [Order] attribute. These tests can get quite lengthy, and in certain cases there's no need to continue running tests in the class if one of the tests fail. I want NUnit to continue on to other classes, but I want it to abort calling any more classes in that specified class.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using NUnit 3.2

Thanks!

Buzz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently any way to stop execution of tests within a class on first error. There is only the command line option `--stoponerror` which stops running all tests on the first error.

The `Order` attribute is new in 3.2. Unlike other frameworks, it was only intended to order your tests, not setup dependencies for your tests. There is an open enhancement on GitHub for a [Test Dependency Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/51), but it hasn't been worked on because people cannot come to a consensus on the design. I think a good first step would be a variation of the `Order` attribute with dependencies, but some people want a full dependency graph. I would recommend that you head over to GitHub and [comment on the issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/51) with your requirements.

Comment: Sad there is a command but no Attribute, I wish .NET would have something that could compete with TestNG's functionality :(